# Pandas long to wide by subsets

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a dataframe of the following format

```
YR    WEEK  ACCOUNT   Tax   AMOUNT   SURCHARGE  Label
2021   1      1       10     5000     5          0
2021   1      2       20     10000    10         1
2021   2      1       20     2000      2         0
2021   2      2        5      10       3         1
2021   3      1       20     10000    10         1
2021   3      2       10     40000    50         1
```

I want to reshape it such that, it results in the following

```
ACCOUNT    YR    WEEK    Tax_1   Amount_1   Surcharge_1    Tax_2   Amount_2   Surcharge_2   Label
1         2021    2      10       5000         5             20     2000        2           0
2         2021    2      20       10000       10             5      10          3           1
1         2021    3      0         2000        2             20     10000       10          1
2         2021    3      5          10       3              10     40000        50          1
```

Each row is `reshaped` such that it is a function of the past 2 rows by account, year and week. And the `Label` is the current label of the `WEEK`
I tried first to `reshape` it to `wide`

```
df.pivot('ACCOUNT', columns=['YR','WEEK'])
```

And was going to try a `reshape` after, but the `pivot`resulted in `NaN` values
Any ideas on how I can achieve this in `pandas`
Thx!

Comment: The logic doesn't make sense, what column(s) do you want to pivot?

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear in describing it. TBH I am not sure if this is called a ````pivot```` either. Essentially, I am looking to rearrange  ````Tax, Amount, Surcharge````such that the ````Tax, Amount, Surcharge```` of  ````Week1```` and ````Tax, Amount, Surcharge```` of ````Week2```` are lined up in one row. The ````Label```` Should still be that of ````Week2````. It can also be thought of as a type ````shift```` but with more than one variable...Hope this helps. If its still not clear, I can try to make a larger example to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not a `pivot`, as `pivot` reshapes the data, while you here want to **duplicate/shift** it (you have more data cells after than before).

To take a simpler example, the goal is to go from something like this (6 values):

```
   id  group value
0   1      1     A
1   1      2     B
2   1      3     C
3   2      1     D
4   2      2     E
5   2      3     F
```

to this (8 values):

```
   id  group_1 value_1  group_2 value_2
0   1        1       A        2       B
1   1        2       B        3       C
2   2        1       D        2       E
3   2        2       E        3       F
```

##### How do we do it?

You can achieve what you want by doing a selection per group and concatenating the two outputs:

```
cols = ['YR', 'ACCOUNT']
g = df.sort_values(by=['YR', 'WEEK']).groupby(cols)

out = (
 pd.concat([g.apply(lambda d: d.drop(columns=cols+['WEEK']).iloc[:-1]).droplevel(-1).add_suffix('_1'),
            g.apply(lambda d: d.drop(columns=cols).iloc[1:]).droplevel(-1).add_suffix('_2')
            ], axis=1)
   .reset_index()
)
```

*NB. the output is slightly different for the labels*

output:

```
     YR  ACCOUNT  Tax_1  AMOUNT_1  SURCHARGE_1  Label_1  WEEK_2  Tax_2  AMOUNT_2  SURCHARGE_2  Label_2
0  2021        1     10      5000            5        0       2     20      2000            2        0
1  2021        1     20      2000            2        0       3     20     10000           10        1
2  2021        2     20     10000           10        1       2      5        10            3        1
3  2021        2      5        10            3        1       3     10     40000           50        1
```

###### slightly more condensed version

*NB. This requires not to have NaNs*

```
cols = ['YR', 'ACCOUNT']
g = df.sort_values(by=['YR', 'WEEK']).groupby(cols)
pd.concat([g.shift().add_suffix('_1'), df.add_suffix('_2')], axis=1).dropna(how='any', axis=0)
```